# Absolute Value Inequality Including Itself

Tags: proof-writing, absolute-value

Given a real number $a$.
Will it be correct to use the following inequality in the proof:

$$-a\le|a|\le a$$

Although "less" and "greater" parts never actually happen, the whole equation will always be valid since depending on the value of $a$ either right or left equality will be true. Therefore the whole inequality is always true.

Is it legit to use this logic in the proof?

Comment: This is not always true.  For example, let $a = -1$.

Comment: Inequalities that are always true include $-|a| \le a \le |a|$ and $-|a| \le -a \le |a|$.

Comment: If you fix the inequalities as shown in the comment, then one of the "less" or "greater" parts definitely _will_ happen. They just won't both happen at the same time; it's either one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's fine (sometimes desired even) to use less information than you actually have for a proof.

However, for your example, you need to specify $a\ge 0$ to make it valid.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could say $ (min-a, a) \le |a| \le max(-a, a)$ but then it's kind of pointless as $|a| = max(-a, a)$

Basically it's best to simply say |a| = {a whenever a $\ge$ 0; -a whenever a $\lt$ 0);

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is absolutely correct and is a commonly used technique (losing the knowledge of equality but setting you up to get a better solution through inequalities). However, your equation only holds for $a \geq 0$, but is otherwise fine. If $a < 0$ then you have $-a \geq |a| \geq a$

Comment: Of course if you know $a\geq0$ then you can just write $|a| = a$.